# Formatting of Numbers in BarLegend

Tags: legending

This question is related [Issue with number formatting in Bar Legend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192179/issue-with-number-formatting-in-bar-legend) but does not fix my problem.

I have a contourplot with logarithmic scaling. Without trying to change anything, the barlegend looks as follows.

[image: barlegend without changes]

All I really want is to cut down the amount of digits to something consistent.  Adapting the answer from the linked question, I did

```
myLegFunc[x_] := 
  x /. {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> ScientificForm[y, 4], 
    Row[{m_, Superscript[b_, e_]}, "\[Times]"] :> 
     NumberForm[m*b^e, {3, 2}]};


 ContourPlot[..., 
  PlotLegends -> {LegendFunction -> myLegFunc}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

The result of which is
[image: result with legend function]

So the fix from that old answer does not work for the values that would be notated in scientific notation anyway. I tried various functions to get it to a number that I could maybe use ScientificForm on but to no avail. My understanding of mathematica is poor, but it feels like the b^e part is a number, but m is not (in the myLegFunc function). I can get 10^{-6} instead of fraction over 100,000. I cannot get it to consider the whole expression as a number.

--

As per the request, this generates a similar issue. I cannot share the original function

```
ContourPlot[x^10, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 Sequence[ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", Exclusions -> None], 
 Contours -> 10, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image: screenshot of output]

---

I have accepted an answer, there is still the issue that depending on settings (plotrange etc.) occasionally the last entry is formatted wrong. I cannot reproduce it in a minimal example, so I am giving up on this. Maybe it is something in my version of mathematica or specific to my data or ..

[image: last entry wrong]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load a minimal example (as Mathematica code) that generates the legend that needs fixing. Thanks.

Comment: @Syed I tried, see edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the option [`LabelingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelingFunction.html) in `BarLegend` (ignore the red syntax highlighting):

```
ContourPlot[x^10, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 Sequence[ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", Exclusions -> None], 
 Contours -> 10, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Automatic, 
   LabelingFunction -> 
   (#3 /. {r_Row :> (r /. {Infinity, _} -> {Infinity, 2}), 
           NumberForm[n_, {_, _}] :> ScientificForm[n, 3]} &)]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, replace `LabelingFunction -> ...` with

```
Charting`TickWrappers -> 
  (# /. {r_Row :> (r /. {Infinity, _} -> {Infinity, 2}), 
         NumberForm[n_, {_, _}] :> ScientificForm[n, 3]} &)
```

to get the same result.

Comment: I had tried LabelingFunction, but simply did not manage to get the row[..] stuff into numbers. This  almost works, despite throwing an error "NumberForm::iprf: Formatting specification {_,_} should be a positive integer or a pair of positive integers." I say almost, because I have two plots and for the last value in the second plot it displays way more digits. I don't know why

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ContourPlot[x^10, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 Sequence[ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", Exclusions -> None], 
 Contours -> 10, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Automatic, None, 
   "Ticks" -> {4.1`*^-10, 1.5*^-8, 5.59`*^-7, 0.00002`, 0.00075`, 
     0.027, 1.`, 37.`, 1300.`, 49000.`}, 
   "TickLabels" -> {"4.1\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-10\)]\
\)", "1.5\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-8\)]\)", 
     "5.6\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-7\)]\)", 
     "2.0\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-5\)]\)", 
     "7.5\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)", 
     "2.7\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-2\)]\)", "1.0", 
     "3.7\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(1\)]\)", 
     "1.3\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(3\)]\)", 
     "4.9\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)"}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 300], ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

**Edit**
I do not think that any tools are available that would enable you to avoid some minimal programming. Nevertheless, find below some conciser way to do the labels:

```
lst = Table[1.*10^(-10 + i), {i, 0, 16, 2}];
lst2 = Map[ScientificForm, lst];
ContourPlot[x^10, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 Sequence[ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", Exclusions -> None], 
 Contours -> 10, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Automatic, None, "Ticks" -> lst, "TickLabels" -> lst2, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 300], ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: This works, but I would like to avoid having to set the labels myself. Will resort to it, if nothing else works. Thanks

Comment: @Bort See the edit

Answer (score 3):

From the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170636/scientific-notation-for-legend-labels)

```
f[x_] := x /. {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> ScientificForm[y, 2]}

ContourPlot[x^10, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 Sequence[ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", Exclusions -> None], 
 Contours -> 10, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
 PlotLegends -> {LegendFunction -> f}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This for me has the same issue as the other answer that occasionally the last entry is formatted wrong. I am giving up in trying to understand this nonsense. I dont know maybe its my old version of mathematica, will edit the image or whatever. I have accepted the other answer because it came earlier